# How to join array with different separator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, separator

```js
var array = ["Red", "Green", "White", "Black", "Gray"];
document.write(array.join("+"));
```

I want it to output like this: `Red+Green-White*Black#Gray`

Comment: you can do this with a `reduce` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```js
// your initial array of elements to join
var array = ["Red", "Green", "White", "Black", "Gray"];

// new list of separators to use
var separators = ["+","-","*","#"];

var joined = array.reduce((output, elem, index) => {
  // always join the next element
  output += elem;

  // add next separator, if we're not at the final element in the array
  if (index < array.length - 1) output += separators[index];

  // return the current edits
  return output;
}, '')

console.log(joined)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce by taking an array for `glue`.

```js
var array = ["Red", "Green", "White", "Black", "Gray"],
    glue = ['+', '-', '*', '#'],
    result = array.reduce((a, b, i) => [a, b].join(glue[(i - 1) % glue.length]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `(i => (a, b) => [a, b].join(separators[++i, i%= separators.length]))(-1)` can just be `(a, b, i) => [a, b].join(separators[i])` ;)

Comment: @VLAZ, the index starts with one.

Comment: You are right! Sorry, I missed that. But then it's `[i-1]` instead of `[i]`. I do appreciate the Scheme style here, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the delimiters are random and don't contain any logic. You can have a look at the following code:

```
var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var delimiters = ['+', '-', '*', '#'];

function customJoin(resultantStr, num) {
    let delimiter = delimiters[Math.floor(Math.random()*delimiters.length)];
  return resultantStr+delimiter+num;
}

console.log(chars.reduce(customJoin))
```

Let me know if this is helpful to you! Happy Coding!